# Como posso registar uma rota no IIS para o meu docker container?

Tags: http, docker

Tenho um serviço `HTTP` que estou a disponibilizar dentro dum *docker container*.

Até agora, para todos os meus serviços `HTTP` eu criava uma regra de redirecionamento (URL Rewrite) no `IIS` que permitia que os meus serviços estivessem disponíveis numa porta diferente da porta padrão do `HTTP` (a porta 80). E também permitia que as minhas aplicações *Web* pudessem fazer requisições aos serviços sem ser necessário implementar *CORS*.

A minha dificuldade neste momento está em saber como posso fazer um processo semelhante para o meu *docker container*. Uma vez que se eu registar os *containers* no `IIS` não terá resultado, já que eles não são acessíveis por máquinas diferentes de onde eles estão hospedados.

Como posso aceder aos serviços dos meus *containers* e continuar a ter as minhas regras de redirecionamento?

Informacoes adicionais:

- O meu `IIS` nao está a correr num container e neste momento queria evitar mete-lo num container
- Por enquanto estou apenas a usar uma máquina com *docker*. Isto quer dizer que nao há *swarms* envovildos. Nem *kubernetes*
- O `IIS` corre numa máquina diferente onde o container corre.
- O `IIS` pode aceder ao host em vez do container caso seja necessário.
- Nao tenho nenhumas redes configuradas para o *docker* neste momento.

Comment: 1. o IIS é também um container?; 2. é um container no mesmo host?; 3. está usando swarm, kubernetes, ...?; 4. estando também o IIS em um container, como estão organizadas as redes?; 5. o IIS não acessa diretamente o container, mas acessaria o host, correto?

Comment: @BrunoCésar Adicionei as informacoes pedidas

Comment: Está publicando a porta para acesso pelo host? Por que se entendi bem, apenas isto irá funcionar, já que o IIS terá acesso ao host docker. Algo como `-p 1234:1234` se está iniciando o container pela CLI mesmo.

Comment: @BrunoCésar Foi isso que eu vi também, mas estava á procura a ver se havia outras opcoes. No meu caso eu faco apenas ligeiramente diferente. Uso o `Expose` e o `-P` O `-P` maiusculo atribui uma porta dinamica no host...

Comment: Não sei se há outra maneira, acredito que não, uma vez que a rede em que o container está é virtual, então, por padrão, apenas o próprio docker e o host a conhecem. Poderá até ser acessível de outras redes externas, mas não vejo o por que disto. Outra coisa é, como bem observou, `-P` irá atribuir uma porta dinâmica no host, pode ser que a rota no IIS deixe de funcionar.

Comment: Nao tem problema uma vez que eu tenho um servico que me ajuda a atualizar a rota no IIS. Inclusivamente fiz um script Powershell para isso. Se voce quiser responder pode responder eu dou +1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como está usando simplesmente um *host* docker e o IIS não é um container/service, a solução seria fazer com que o teu IIS acesse o *host* docker.

Como as redes criadas pelo docker são virtuais, tanto a `default` quanto qualquer outra explicitamente criada, diretamente apenas o *host* e o docker própria dito a conhecem, o que impede que, por padrão, o servidor que hospeda o IIS tenha acesso a qualquer rede gerenciada pelo docker, mas de forma mais facilitada ao *host* docker.

Então, publicando as portas para acesso pelo *host* - `--publish , -p` ou `--publish-all , -P`, considerando que está usando a CLI do docker - seria a alternativa para que você crie as rotas no seu servidor HTTP.

Quando usando *swarm* existem algumas alternativas como o [routing mesh](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/ingress/) que facilita o acesso por recursos fora do *swarm*.

Comment: Legal ainda nao conhecia esse mesh